# How do I save my current record while in a user form, and then once saved continue to work on it?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I currently have a form in which I have alot of text and comboboxes. For this example I am only going to focus on two of them "QuoteID" and "Contact".

When I first open my form the QuoteID combobox (Which is the primary Key) says (New) or in other words, the control source for QuoteID combobox is set to the QuoteID (PK) in the table. I want the form to have (New) for the primary key when it first opens.

Contact is a textbox; its control source is set to contact in the table.

I currently have data entry = yes and cycle = current record.

My goal is when I am working on a new quote I want to be able to save the current record that I am working on, and then once saved I can then continue to work on it saving it as I go.

My problem That I am having is; When I click my command button called "Save Quote" It adds the data from the form to the table correctly. When I click it again it adds a new record, giving me multiple instances of the same quote.

```
Private Sub SaveQuote_Click()
    Dim miscQuote As Recordset
    Set miscQuote = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblQuotes")

    miscQuote.AddNew
    miscQuote![Contact] = frmQuote3.Value
    miscQuote![QuoteID] = frmQuote1.Value
    miscQuote.Update
    miscQuote.Close

    Set RecSet = Nothing

End Sub
```

frmQuote3 is a text box and frmQuote1 is a combobox on my form.

Comment: If your form based on tblQuotes, you don't need to add new record using recordset or `INSERT`. New record will be added automatically when you change any data in any bound field. And you don't need to save changed data, it will be saved automatically when you close the form or change record.

Comment: For immediate saving form data call `Me.Dirty = False`

Comment: I forgot to mention that yes only this part of the code is based on tblQuotes, I have many other tables that are linked to this form. I have tried working with sub forms but get nothing but errors. I would really like to use vba to make my life easier. I hate subforms

Comment: Sergey S. That works great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set *Dirty* to False to save the record:

```
Private Sub SaveQuote_Click()

    If Me.Dirty = True Then
        Me.Dirty = False
    End If

End Sub
```